# does a matrix commutes with its resolvet?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a non singular matrix, and $\omega$ a complex number such that
$$
\det(I\omega-A)\neq 0 \forall \omega
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
Does the following equality holds?
$$
(I\omega-A)^{-1}A = A(I\omega-A)^{-1}
$$
How to prove it?

Comment: multiply both sides by $(I\omega-A)$

Comment: The answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that $(I\omega-A)^{-1}(I\omega-A )= (I\omega-A)(I\omega-A)^{-1}$.

Can you take it from here ?